SqlAlchemy Autocommit mode not commiting
Having some issues setting up an autocommit session
The create_audit_log function doesn't "create" the new record without having s.commit() afterwards
SqlAlchemy version 2.0.30
psycopg2-binary version 2.9.9
My code
import logging
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, inspect
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from .models import Audit


class DBManager:

    audit_model = Audit

    def __init__(self, db_url):
        self.engine = create_engine(db_url, isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT")
        self.session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)

        if not inspect(self.engine).has_table(self.audit_model.__tablename__):
            self.audit_model.metadata.create_all(bind=self.engine)

    def create_audit_log(self, requester, operation, status, started_at, ended_at):
        with self.session() as s:
            audit_log = self.audit_model(requester=requester, operation=operation, status=status, started_at=started_at, ended_at=ended_at)
            s.add(audit_log)


My interpretation of this section of the docs - particularly 'The “autocommit_session” continues to have transactional semantics' is that you need to call session.commit() even though you are using an autocommit connection if you want to commit a change.

In AUTOCOMMIT mode you don't need to s.commit() but you still need to s.flush() before exiting the context manager block.

following the docs -> SQLAlchemy methods like .begin(), .commit() and .rollback() pass silently.
so seems I don't need it ..

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/orm_data_manipulation.html#flushing

Was solved as follows
def create_audit_log(self, requester, operation, status, started_at, ended_at):
        with self.session() as s, s.begin():
            audit_log = self.audit_model(requester=requester, operation=operation, status=status, started_at=started_at, ended_at=ended_at)
            s.add(audit_log)

